# Chefbuillderror when trying to install mobsf

Tags: python, python-3.x, mobsf

```
at ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chef.py:147 in _prepare
      143│
      144│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      145│
      146│             if error is not None:
    → 147│                 raise error from None
      148│
      149│             return path
      150│
      151│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:
```

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with pillow (10.1.0) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running `pip wheel --use-pep517 "pillow (==10.1.0)".`

When trying to install mobsf I get the following error during the installation of pillow, I've been trying to find a way to resolve the error by making pillow (10.1.0) compatible with PEP 517 builds but couldn't do it. Can anyone help in resolving this error?

Tried upgrading pillow to it's latest version but of no use